# Typescript - evaluate arithmetic expressions

Tags: typescript

How can I evaluate arithmetic expressions in Typescript? An example is '(3+5*(-3+-1))'.

Eval(...) is forbidden.

A suggested solution is not accepted at runtime:

```
let input = '(3+5)';
let resultNumber = (new Function( 'return (' + input + ')'))();
```

The error is:

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>               at new Function ()

Math.js with 136kb footprint (compressed) is too large in my for evaluating simple expressions. It could be customized by limiting the functionality.

So, do you have a small typescript file / service that can evaluate arithmetic expressions? Of course the unary minus/plus should work properly.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form) while asked for Java might contain some info which can help you out. Maybe you can rewrite some of the code to Javascript/Typescript?

Comment: Make no mistake, if you think `eval()` is bad, then `new Function('');` is just as bad for the exact same reasons.

Comment: @Mathyn - GREAT - via your post I found a very compact evaluation of arithmetic expressions. Can you add this link to an Answer, and I will +1 it! https://stackoverflow.com/a/26227947/3143823

Comment: @tjm1706 I'd love to but I'd have to rewrite the Java code to Typescript myself for it to be a proper answer.

Comment: I am already rewriting the code. You pointed me the way for a solution. So you can post that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Mathyn I found a piece of good Java code created by @Boann. I migrated it to Typescript, there you have it.

Below you also find the Karma test code, so you can see what is possible: +, -, (unary), *, ^, /, braces, (value), sin, cos, tan, sqrt, etc.

How to use it? In Angular, you can access it via dependency injection. Otherwise you can create an object. You can specify via a boolean (here 'true') to get the result as an integer.

```
arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('10 + 2 * 6')   // shows 22.0
arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('10 + 2 * 6', true)   // shows 22 (integer only)
```

The complete Typescript source code is:

```
export class ArithmeticExpressionEvaluator {
    static INVALID_NUMBER = -1234567.654;
    str: string;
    pos = -1;
    ch: string;

    evaluate(expression: string): number {
        return this.evaluateAll(expression, false);
    }

    evaluateAll(expression: string, resultIsInteger: boolean): number {
        this.str = expression;
        pos = -1;
        const outcome = this.parse();
        if (resultIsInteger) {
            return Math.round(outcome);
        }
        return outcome;
    }

    nextChar() {
        this.ch = (++this.pos < this.str.length) ? this.str.charAt(this.pos) : null;
    }

    eat(charToEat: string): boolean {
        while (this.ch === ' ') {
            this.nextChar();
        }
        if (this.ch === charToEat) {
            this.nextChar();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    parse(): number {
        this.nextChar();
        const x = this.parseExpression();
        if (this.pos < this.str.length) {
            return ArithmeticExpressionEvaluator.INVALID_NUMBER;
        }
        return x;
    }

    parseExpression(): number {
        let x = this.parseTerm();
        for (; ; ) {
            if (this.eat('+')) {  // addition
                x += this.parseTerm();
            } else if (this.eat('-')) {  // subtraction
                x -= this.parseTerm();
            } else {
                return x;
            }
        }
    }

    parseTerm(): number {
        let x = this.parseFactor();
        for (; ;) {
            if (this.eat('*')) {  // multiplication
                x *= this.parseFactor();
            } else if (this.eat('/')) {  // division
                x /= this.parseFactor();
            } else {
                return x;
            }
        }
    }

    parseFactor(): number {
        if (this.eat('+')) {  // unary plus
            return this.parseFactor();
        }
        if (this.eat('-')) { // unary minus
            return -this.parseFactor();
        }
        let x;
        const startPos = this.pos;
        if (this.eat('(')) { // parentheses
            x = this.parseExpression();
            this.eat(')');
        } else if ((this.ch >= '0' && this.ch <= '9') || this.ch === '.') { // numbers
            while ((this.ch >= '0' && this.ch <= '9') || this.ch === '.') {
                this.nextChar();
            }
            x = parseFloat(this.str.substring(startPos, this.pos));
        } else if (this.ch >= 'a' && this.ch <= 'z') { // functions
            while (this.ch >= 'a' && this.ch <= 'z') {
                this.nextChar();
            }
            const func = this.str.substring(startPos, this.pos);
            x = this.parseFactor();
            if (func === 'sqrt') {
                x = Math.sqrt(x);
            } else if (func === 'sin') {
                x = Math.sin(this.degreesToRadians(x));
            } else if (func === 'cos') {
                x = Math.cos(this.degreesToRadians(x));
            } else if (func === 'tan') {
                x = Math.tan(this.degreesToRadians(x));
            } else {
                return ArithmeticExpressionEvaluator.INVALID_NUMBER;
            }
        } else {
            return ArithmeticExpressionEvaluator.INVALID_NUMBER;
        }
        if (this.eat('^')) {  // exponentiation
            x = Math.pow(x, this.parseFactor());
        }
        return x;
    }

    degreesToRadians(degrees: number): number {
        const pi = Math.PI;
        return degrees * (pi / 180);
    }
}
```

The Karma test code is:

```
import {ArithmeticExpressionEvaluator} from './arithmetic-expression-evaluator.service';

describe('Arithmetic Expression Evaluation', () => {
    let arithmeticExpressionEvaluator: ArithmeticExpressionEvaluator;
    beforeEach(() => {
        arithmeticExpressionEvaluator = new ArithmeticExpressionEvaluator();
    });
    it('Arithmetic Expression Evaluation - double result', () => {
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('10 + 2 * 6')).toBe(22.0);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('100 * 2 + 12')).toBe(212.0);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('100 * 2 + -12')).toBe(188.0);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('100 * (2) + -12')).toBe(188.0);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('-100 * 2 + 12')).toBe(-188.0);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('100 * 2 ^ 12')).toBe(409600.0);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('100 * ( 2 + 12 )')).toBe(1400.0);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('(100) * (( 2 ) + (12) )')).toBe(1400.0);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluate('100 * ( 2 + 12 ) / 14')).toBe(100.0);
    });
    it('Arithmetic Expression Evaluation - integer result', () => {
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAll('10 + 2 * 6',  true)).toBe(22);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAll('100 * 2 + 12' , true)).toBe(212);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAll('100 * 2 + -12', true)).toBe(188);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAll('100 * (2) + -12', true)).toBe(188);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAll('-100 * 2 + 12' , true)).toBe(-188);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAll('100 * 2 ^ 12', true)).toBe(409600);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAll('100 * ( 2 + 12 )', true)).toBe(1400);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAll('(100) * (( 2 ) + (12) )', true)).toBe(1400);
        expect(arithmeticExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAll('100 * ( 2 + 12 ) / 14', true)).toBe(100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If `eval()` is off the table, you need to write a custom DSL and write your own parser. To some extend you will build what `eval()` already does for you, but presumably a more restricted version without all the javascript features.

Alternatively find an existing NPM package.